# An array with no pre-defined limit to the number of elements that it can contain

Tags: c

For my project, I have to have a stack stored in the heap. I am using an array for this however the array is not allowed to have a pre-defined limit.

I am not sure how to have an array in C with no limit. The code below is my best attempt and is producing the error message "size of array has a non-integer type". Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



 int main()
 {
    int *g = malloc(100 *sizeof(int));
    free(g);
    int array[g];


    printf("the array spot 0 is \n");
    scanf("&i\n", array[0]);

    printf("the array spot 1 is \n");
    scanf("&i\n", array[1]);

    printf("the array place 1 is %i and %i\n",array[0],array[1]);

    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Is it a requirement to use array for implementing your stack? If no, consider implementing your stack with struct and pointers. This way you will allocate dynamically memory when a new element needs to be inserted and avoid messing with `realloc`.

Comment: `have a stack stored in the heap`..kind of oxymoron...

Comment: Please what's the purpose of this: `int *g = malloc(100 *sizeof(int));
    free(g);`?

Comment: This `scanf("&i\n", ...` scans in nothing. You probably meant `scanf("%i\n", ...`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, let me tell you, there is nothing *"without a limit"*, you are after all limited by the memory (physical or virtual) on the system.

That said, if you want to have an array without the size pre-defined and the size is determined in runtime, you have two options:

1. You can consider using [VLA (Variable length array)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array). The memory allocation for this is implantation dependent, for example, `gcc` allocates the VLAs on stack - so you are size-bound by the stack size on your system.
2. On the other hand, if you are okay with dynamic memory allocation, you can use a pointer and use `malloc()` and `realloc()` to assign and resize the allocated memory. The pointer is not going to be an array (and vice versa), but other than that, there is no generic reason that it should not fit your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstood what you do with `malloc`

This line:

```
  int *g = malloc(100 *sizeof(int));
```

Is acutally creating an array of size 100

So you can use

```
 g[0]   
 g[1]
```

To access element in your array

And for the `free` part : Thiss method destroy (free) your array so you have to call it when you don't need your array anymore (ie at the end of the main in your case)

Comment: All true, but how does this answer this question?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

typedef struct {
    size_t  num;    /* Number of ints in array */
    size_t  max;    /* Number of ints allocated for */
    int    *array;
} intarray;
#define  INTARRAY_INIT  { 0, 0, NULL }

/* Discard an intarray. */
void intarray_free(intarray *iarr)
{
    if (iarr) {
        free(iarr->array); /* Note: free(NULL) is safe to do. */
        iarr->num = 0;
        iarr->max = 0;
        iarr->array = NULL;
    }
}

/* Ensure there is room for at least 'more' additional ints in the intarray. */
void intarray_need(intarray *iarr, const size_t  more)
{
    int    *array;
    size_t  max;

    /* No intarray specified? */
    if (!iarr) {
        fprintf(stderr, "intarray_need(): iarr == NULL!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Calculate size needed. */
    max = iarr->num + more;

    /* Array already large enough? */
    if (iarr->max >= max)
        return;

    /* Growth policy: increase allocated size,
       to avoid reallocating in too small chunks. */
    if (max < 8) {
        /* Always at least 8 ints. */
        max = 8;  
    } else
    if (max < 524288) {
        /* Grow by 50% up to 524288. */
        max = (3 * max) / 2;
    } else {
        /* Round up to next multiple of 262144, less 32. */
        max = (max | 262143) + 262145 - 32;
    }

    /* Allocate. */
    array = realloc(iarr->array, max * sizeof iarr->array[0]);
    if (!array) {
        fprintf(stderr, "intarray_need(): Out of memory; num == %zu, more == %zu, new max == %zu.\n",
                        iarr->num, more, max);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    iarr->max   = max;
    iarr->array = array;
}

/* Add one int to the intarray. */
void intarray_add(intarray *iarr, const int val)
{
    /* We need room for at least one more int. */
    intarray_need(iarr, 1);

    /* Append. */
    iarr->array[iarr->num++] = val;
}

int main(void)
{
    intarray  data = INTARRAY_INIT;
    size_t    i;
    int       val;

    /* Parse ints from standard input. */
    while (scanf("%d", &val) == 1) {
        intarray_add(&data, val);
    }

    /* Why did the scan fail? */
    if (ferror(stdin)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error reading from standard input.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } else
    if (feof(stdin)) {
        printf("All input converted successfully.\n");
        /* Fall through */
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Warning: Could not parse all standard input.\n");
        /* Fall through */
    }

    printf("Read %zu ints:\n", data.num);
    for (i = 0; i < data.num; i++)
        printf("%12d\n", data.array[i]);

    intarray_free(&data);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The `intarray` type is a structure type, which contains members `max`, `num`, and `array`. It is initialized to known values using `INTARRAY_INIT`.

The `intarray_free()` function discards an intarray.

The `intarray_more()` function is the interesting one. It ensures there is enough memory allocated for the specified number of additional ints.  Note that `realloc(NULL, SIZE)` is equivalent to `malloc(SIZE)`; because the structure was properly initialized (`INTARRAY_INIT`), we can just reallocate it to whatever size we might need.

The resize policy shown here is only an example, and is roughly typical of what I myself might use. It has three parts: a minimum allocation size, an exponential growth part, and linear growth part.  The intent is that the growth works for both small and very large arrays without huge drawbacks.  The really large linear growth part (`max = (max | 262143) + 262145 - 8;`) is a curiosity, as it rounds up to the next multiple of 2<sup>18</sup> = 262144 less 8 ints using simple binary operations: the idea is to allow the C library to allocate a chunk that is a multiple of 2<sup>18</sup>, including its own overhead. The underlying hope is that the OS can do that (allocation in multiples of a large power of two, specifically) more efficiently than other sizes. Think of it as an example of what you might see in real life; not what you should do.

While `intarray_add()` adds just one int at a time, you can easily write another function that adds several at the time; just remember to call `intarray_need()` first to ensure there is enough memory allocated for the new integers.

If you compile and run the program, it will read integers from standard input until you supply non-integer input, or end of input is encountered (if you e.g. redirect input from a file).

For example, if you run the program as `program.exe < file.txt` or `./program < file.txt` with `file` containing

```
1 2
3 4 5
-6 -7
-8
9
```

then the output is

```
All input converted successfully.
Read 9 ints:
       1
       2
       3
       4
       5
      -6
      -7
      -8
       9
```

The only limitation is the amount of memory available for the program.

There is also one bug left in the program: Possible overflow when calculating `max` in `intarray_need()`, and the number of bytes to be reallocated (the second parameter to `realloc()`). These can be checked, because all parameters are of type `size_t`, which is some unsigned integer type; and in C, unsigned integer types use modulo arithmetic (that is, as if all computations were made *modulo* `UINT_MAX + 1`).

Answer (score -1):

You could initialize one size and then double the size whenever you run out of space and dump all of your elements into the newly created array.

This post talks about implementing that in C
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/64423/implementing-an-arraylist